# Get Email address of Facebook user from post comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get email address from comments in posts of the Facebook page, but with no luck. I am requesting this URL:

```
feed?fields=message,id,description,created_time,from,comments{from,email, id,created_time,message},story
```

I am using v2.6 of Graph API. Is  there any way for getting the mail in single call or I need to send another request where I will call the ID of the Facebook User and then access the email address which will be bad practice if there is a lot of comments and users.

Comment: You will not _get_ an e-mail address from the API, unless the individual user grants your app permission to access it first. (And that not every Facebook user does have an e-mail address on file with Facebook, f.e. if they registered using only their mobile, comes on top of that.) // What do you want/need those e-mail addresses for in the first place? You know that you are not allowed to send e-mail to users just because they commented somewhere on your page, right?

Comment: I know that the user need to grant permissions for using the email address, and if the user have the email address and grant the permissions for using, I don't see any reason why I am not allowed to use his email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the correct syntax for the Field Expansion that you’re already making use of:

> ```
> feed?fields=message,id,description,created_time,from,comments{from,email, id,created_time,message},story
> ```

The email of the comment creator would be a “property” of the `from` structure, so you can use

```
/feed?fields=comments{from{id,name,email},…}
```

to get the email of people who commented (and granted your app permission to read their e-mail upfront.)

Comment: I have tried this combination, but still does not work... It returns all information except the email. I also tried the test this in the Graph API Explorer and it doesn't work. I am sure that i can access the email address of the testing data, because I retrieving the email from the user in Conversations part. Any other hints?

Comment: Did the user grant you user_email permission?

Comment: Yes, as I said, I can access email address in separate call using the user ID, but I want to get in the feed request.

Comment: Might depend on what type of access token you are using.

Comment: I have tried with both options, user token and page token... still same.

Comment: Sorry, don’t know what else to tell you – it works for me, if I request the feed and comments for a page, and for users that have already granted the app `email` permission.

Comment: I cant get email when I trying to get with Page Access Token, but if I try with User Access Token, then is working as expected. Any ideas why?

Comment: Dunno, some privacy reasons maybe. You can always file a bug report and ask them if this intentional, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs